# How to request dynamically created JS files using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, api

We have a lot of these small sets of data that populates our select dropdowns in our view. For example, gender, countries, shirt sizes, country contact codes, etc..

These data sets don't normally change so I'm thinking what would be the best option to retrieve these data to our views.

1. Create endpoints for them. So I would have something like below

   http://dom.com/countries

   http://dom.com/genders

   http://dom.com/shirt_sizes

   Problem is I would make several "expensive" http requests just to retrieve these information.
2. Create a module and hardcode these values in a service

   angular.module('OptionsModule')
   .factory('options', function() {
       return {
           genders: ['M','F'],
           // others
       }
   }

   Problem is some options I still need to load from the database. For example,
   the countries list. So I need a way to dynamically create this module from the server

I kinda prefer option #2. But how do you generate js files dynamically from php and how do I request for it using angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mix of your two points is good. Use hardcoded values for small lists and backend requests for long/DB-placed data.

You need not send js file, you just send [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp) object. In PHP you get it by [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and in JS you get your JS object (you need nothing).